# how to draw classifier in SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

suppose I have w and b, then how to draw the classifier in Matlab? suppose the nodes are in 2-D space, that is to say, x=(x1,x2).

I've tried several methods, but can't draw the classifier y=w^T x+b? Any help?

Comment: Could you add some of the several methods you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `w` is a 2d vector as well.

Say that you have the following data:

```
datawX = [1,1,3,2,0,0,0]
datawY = [2,0,1,4,2,1,0]

databX = [1,0,2,5,4,4,2]
databY = [1,0,2,2,4,4,4]
```

Then you calculate the classifier using the Support-vector machine method.
Say the result is `w=[3,1]` and `b=1.5`, in that case the direction of the vector is perpendicular to `w` so `d=[-w(2),w(1)]`. So you can define two points p1 and p2.

after performing the svm:

```
p1=-b*w
p2=d-b*w

w=[3,1]
b=1.5

d=[-w(2),w(1)]
p1=-b*w
p2=d-b*w
scatter(dataw, 'r')
hold on
scatter(datab, 'g')
hold on
plot([p1;p2],'b');
```